# Confusion in setting up Gsuite email [Domain: Namecheap, Host: AWS S3, Serving: Cloudfront]

Tags: dns, gmail, google-workspace

I have a problem setting up GSuite gmail. I can send out emails to other accounts; however, I cannot receive any emails from outside. My admin page says

> Setting up email is taking longer than expected
>   We were unable to set up email, or your domain host is taking longer than expected to update your information.

My domain is registered with Namecheap. But it is served from Amazon S3. And the "https" certificate is verified and served through CloudFront. When setting up "MX Records" for Gsuite gmail, I set up in Namecheap. But it has been more than 72 hours, and Gsuite is still not picking up. In my situation, do I have to set up "MX Records" through Route53 because it is being hosted in Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup MX records however if your domain is still not verified with G Suite you will not be able to use emails or any other service. Make sure to:

1. Your domain has been verified [Verify your domain for G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216?hl=en).
2. MX Records are setup properly [G Suite MX record values](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en)
3. If you domain is verified make sure that all apps on Admin Console > Apps >  G Suite are enabled.
4. Also as recommendation set up [SPF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en), [DKIM](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en&ref_topic=7564555&visit_id=636983927126326312-3020794159&rd=1) and [DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/topic/7562942?hl=en&ref_topic=7556597) to authenticate email.

If you are still not able to receive emails I would suggest to contact G Suite Support. Also make sure where your Domain NS servers are pointing to, there is where you have to update the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an issue with Google, every domain's MX records are public, you can easily inspect your domain and verify if the MX records are already setup to Google, check https://mxtoolbox.com/ and make sure that the MX records are already ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM, if it's not, then make sure that the MX is updated in your NameServers (not necesarily your domain provider), same online tools can easily tell you which is your active NameServers (Google NS lookup tools).